# Unable to open or rename PDF files uploaded with Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, pdf, permissions, windows-10

I am currently encountering issues with uploading PDF files from my **Symfony 6.4.3** application. Indeed, I managed to upload PDF files using **UploadedFile**, and I find these files correctly stored in the designated directory **"public/pdf/"**. However, I face difficulties when attempting to open or delete these PDF files without administrative rights. This is the only folder causing issues in my application, as I have other directories where I upload .json or .txt files without any problems.

Here are excerpts from my code :

```
<?php

//src/Controller/AwsExtractController.php


namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\AwsPdfDocument;
use App\Form\AwsPdfDocumentFormType;

use App\Service\FileUploader;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;


class AwsExtractController extends AbstractController
{

    public function __construct()
    {}

    /**
     * @Route("/documents/scan", name="scan_documents")
     * Fonction permettant de transférer les documents dans le 
     * bucket S3, puis d'analyser ces documents avec AWS Textract.
     * 
     * 3 Requêtes AWS
     * 
     * @param Request                $request
     * @param EntityManagerInterface $entityManager
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, FileUploader $fileUploader)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(AwsPdfDocumentFormType::class);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        $analysedPdfs = $entityManager->getRepository(AwsPdfDocument::class)->findAll();


        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) 
        {
            $files = $form->get('files')->getData();

            if ($files) 
            {
                foreach ($files as $file) 
                {
                    //PROBLEM
                    $fileName = $fileUploader->upload($file);
                    dd("end");
                }
            }
        }
        return $this->render(
            'aws/aws_scan_document/index.html.twig',
            [
                'form' => $form->createView(),
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

```
<?php

// src/Service/FileUploader.php

namespace App\Service;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\Exception\FileException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Symfony\Component\String\Slugger\SluggerInterface;

class FileUploader
{
    public function __construct(
        private string $targetDirectory,
        private SluggerInterface $slugger,
    ) {
    }

    public function upload(UploadedFile $file): string
    {
        $originalFilename = pathinfo($file->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        $safeFilename = $this->slugger->slug($originalFilename);
        $fileName = $safeFilename . '-' . uniqid() . '.' . $file->guessExtension();
        try 
        {
            $file->move($this->getTargetDirectory(), $fileName);
        } catch (FileException $e) {
            // ... handle exception if something happens during file upload
        }

        return $fileName;
    }

    public function getTargetDirectory(): string
    {
        return $this->targetDirectory;
    }
}
```

- [When I open the PDF.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tysQA.png)
- [When I want to delete the PDF.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTtng.png)
- [When I copy the PDF from 'public/pdf/' to 'My Documents' and want to delete it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJYq3.png)

I am using :

- **PHP 8.1.27**
- **Composer 2.6.4**
- **Symfony web server**
- **Windows 10 Professional**

So far, I have tried changing the directory where PDF files are saved, but it didn't make any difference. I also attempted to manually change the permissions of the directory and files, but still no luck. Next, I commented out the Symfony code for uploading files and replaced it with pure PHP code, but that didn't yield any results either. Lastly, I created a virtual machine running Windows 10, deployed the application, and it worked, but I'm not sure why and how.

I want to express my sincere gratitude to everyone who takes the time to help me. Your willingness to offer your assistance is precious and greatly appreciated. Whether by answering my questions, sharing advice, or proposing solutions, each contribution is of great value to me.